# Google tracking and conversion code from callback

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api, payment

I think most of you knows this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = <MY_CONVERSION_ID>;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "<MY_LABEL>";
var google_conversion_value = <?=$this->controller->conversion?>;
var google_conversion_currency = "HUF";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
```

My problem is to figure out, where to place this code. And not only this, the facebook tracking, and other client side tracking codes.

We did put it on the `Thank you for your order` page, but what happens when after a successfull paypal or a bankcard payment happens, but user after that closes his browser? Tracking code won't run.

It should be happens at the callback URL, when paypal or bank notify the provider about the success of payment. The problem is, that callback is run on server side in background.

I thought, I can make a page what I can call with `wget` and pass the order id to it, but `wget` is not a browser, so it won't run javascript.

How can be it is done?